# JBoss 7: EJB over HTTP

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x

Hi I'm porting our EJB Server/Client application from JBoss 5.2 to JBoss 7.

Currently the EJB's on the Server are invoked over an HTTP Invoker on the server. (also includeing JNDI...)

I have read that the guys at JBoss have developed a new HTTP Server for WildFly where it should work like cham, but I haven found a way to do this under JBoss 7 (EAP 6.1)

Greetings
Florian

Comment: Here I found some informations for EAP 4: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EJBJMSAndJNDIOverHTTPWithUnifiedInvoker

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in any official releases of as7 or EAP6

There was an experimental build that had limited support, but probably best avoided. Message me directly if you still want to try it for non production use